# Java how to prompt user to save a word doc

Tags: java, ms-word, save, command-prompt

I've found a VB and a C# version of this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-5), but I haven't been able to find it in Java. 
I have a string that I want to prompt the user to save their word document as and let them decide where. I have already opened the file using:

```
    public static void sendCommand(String command){
    try {  
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C " + command);  
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(  
            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
            String line = null;  
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {  
                System.out.println(line);  
                }  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }}
    public static void unzipOpenToSave(String zipName3){
        command = "cmd.exe /c move \"" + zipName3 + ".docx.zip\"  \"" + zipName3 + ".docx\"";
        sendCommand(command);

        //here we need to open the document and prompt to save as the name they just created
        String unzippedPath = wholePath.substring(0,wholePath.length() - 4);
        command = "rundll32 url.dll, FileProtocolHandler " + unzippedPath;
        sendCommand(command);
    }
```

I found the idea of the code in two different pages on this site. So, next I would need to open a prompt to save with the string already in where they would type the name. I was thinking either use the same method using the command prompt or just use Java. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably going to want to use [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html) for this, assuming you want to do it graphically. JFileChooser is a good choice.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html

Also, [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/334813/GUI/java/Save-Dialog-JFIleChooser) is a good example.

Comment: Is there not a way to tap into the save-as box that already exists in Microsoft Word through Java? I feel like it would be easier that way rather than creating the option for routing where the file is saved, but I will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a Word API for Java, which seems overly complicated, and I'm honestly not sure it exists. I'll look into it and get back to you if I do happen to find one.

Answer (score 1):

That wasn't too bad. I created a frame, added the filechooser to the frame, modified what the "approve button" said, set the mode so it would display the name I wanted, and set action to when the buttons were pressed (actually saving or rewriting the file). Here's what worked:

```
JFrame saveFrame = new JFrame();
    saveFrame.setVisible(true);
    String unzippedPath = fullPath.substring(0,fullPath.length() - 4);
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
    jfc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(unzippedPath));
    jfc.setSelectedFile(new File(newSavedFile4));
    jfc.setApproveButtonText("Save");

    jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

    int result = jfc.showSaveDialog(null);
    if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        in = new File(unzippedPath);
        out = new File(jfc.getSelectedFile().toString() + ".docx");
        System.out.println(out.getAbsolutePath());
        int BUF_SIZE = (int) in.length();

        FileInputStream fiss = new FileInputStream(in);
        FileOutputStream foss = new FileOutputStream(out);
        try{
            byte[]buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
            int i = 0;
            while((i = fiss.read(buf)) != -1){
                foss.write(buf, 0, i);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            throw e;
        }
        finally{
            if(fiss != null) fiss.close();
            if(foss != null) foss.close();
        }
        saveFrame.setVisible(false);
    }
    else if(result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){
        saveFrame.setVisible(false);
    }

    JPanel SPanel = new JPanel();
    SPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    SPanel.add(jfc);



    saveFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    saveFrame.add(SPanel);
    saveFrame.pack();
    saveFrame.setTitle("Save your Doc");
    saveFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Thanks Luke D! +1 if I could ( I don't think I have enough points yet)
(I'm the original poster and can't remember my password, sorry)